Are questions about federal tax credits on topic?
See Federal Tax Credits for Energy Efficiency. I voted to close, thinking of it as a service related topic, but now I'm second-guessing that decision. I also couldn't find anything in the Help Center to clear up the matter.

I'd say No. Sounds financial rather than how to DIY. More like a fit for IRS.SE if such a thing existed.

There is effectively an “IRS.SE”: Personal Finance and Money. It’s not US-exclusive, but this sort of tax credit question is definitely in scope there.

That particular question was purely financial.
A question about whether or not something qualified for a tax credit would be more on-topic.  I.e. I don't think that there should be a bright line rule against tax credit questions.
For example, a question about whether replacing the insulation in the walls counts as a home envelope improvement would make better use of the expertise on DIY.SE than Money.SE.  That kind of question should be on-topic.

"a question about whether replacing the insulation in the walls counts as a home envelope improvement" would 100% be a matter of interpreting the tax code, which is a Money.SE question. DIY is about doing the work - we don't care how you pay for it or who subsidizes the cost.

I am not 100% sure here. On the one hand, this type of thing very much fits into DIY - figuring out what improvements to do and/or when to do them for maximum tax advantage is something very useful and is something very much under the control of the DIYer, whether they are doing the work themselves or contracting it out.
The only problem is that these rules change, sometimes every year, sometimes every few years. And when they change the old advice becomes obsolete, and questions/answers are preferred that are, as much as possible, timeless.
